defining and accessing a list to build the content of a popup menu button including icons
In _HomePageState I have a PopupMenuButton defined as
          PopupMenuButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return <PopupMenuItem>[
                PopupMenuItem(
                  onTap: () {
                    BlocProvider.of<BlocAuth>(context)
                        .add(Setting8EventAuth());
                  },
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                    title: Text('Settings'),
                  ),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  onTap: () {
                    BlocProvider.of<BlocAuth>(context)
                        .add(SignOut8EventAuth());
                  },
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                    title: Text('Logout'),
                  ),
                ),
              ];
            },

I would like to set a list of items related to the content PopupMenuButton and call that list rather than multiplying the same code for each item.
Still in _HomePageState (even though eventually I would like to move it elsewhere), based on
Flutter - PopupMenuButton - add an item manually after adding items from a list I have defined
  List<PopupMenuContent> items = [
    PopupMenuContent(
      name: 'Profile',
      iconFile: 'person.jpg',
      event: 'Profile8EventAuth()',
    ),
    PopupMenuContent(
      name: 'Settings',
      iconFile: 'settings.jpg',
      event: 'Settings8EventAuth()',
    ),
    PopupMenuContent(
      name: 'Logout',
      iconFile: 'logout.jpg',
      event: 'SignOut8EventAuth()',
    ),
  ];

which I hoped to call in PopupMenuButton with something close to
          PopupMenuButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return items.map((item) {
                return PopupMenuItem(
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.${item.iconFile}),
                    title: Text(item.name),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    BlocProvider.of<BlocAuth>(context).add(item.event as AbstEventAuth);
                  },
                );
              }).toList();
            },
          )

I'm not sure casting in BlocProvider will work, but the first issue is with error message I get is related to leading: Icon(Icons.${item.iconFile}),.
Even though not that neat, I could set String itemIF = item.iconFile; between the 2 returns, but then I cannot insert it in leading: Icon(Icons.xxxAboutHerexxxx),.
Any suggestion ?

use IconData for your icon in items list to define the icon not the string. Same goes for your function.
Redefine the PopupMenuContent class
class PopupMenuContent {
  final String name;
  final IconData iconData;
  final Function event;

  PopupMenuContent({required this.name, required this.iconData, required this.event});
}

Now make list accordingly
 List<PopupMenuContent> items = [
    PopupMenuContent(
      name: 'Profile',
      iconData: Icons.person,
      event: () {
        BlocProvider.of<BlocAuth>(context).add(Profile8EventAuth());
      },
    ),
    PopupMenuContent(
      name: 'Settings',
      iconData: Icons.settings,
      event: () {
        BlocProvider.of<BlocAuth>(context).add(Settings8EventAuth());
      },
    ),
    PopupMenuContent(
      name: 'Logout',
      iconData: Icons.logout,
      event: () {
        BlocProvider.of<BlocAuth>(context).add(SignOut8EventAuth());
      },
    ),
  ];

build fn
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
        return items.map((item) {
          return PopupMenuItem(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(item.iconData),
              title: Text(item.name),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              item.event();
            },
          );
        }).toList();
      },
    );
  }


Thanks, it got me right on track as context needed to be passed over, so that I've settled with (
PopupMenuContent(
name: 'Logout',
iconData: Icons.logout,
event: (BuildContext context) {
BlocProvider.of(context).add(SignOut8EventAuth());
},
),

if the answer is correct and helpful, then mark it as answer
